# Can't access JtextField Values in second JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am trying since 1 hour but I can't access my jtextField from JPanel to Jpanel1.
I am working on a course project in which I have to show the name of the log in user in the JPanel using jlabel but I can't access the jTextField in JPanel from jpanel1.
I make my JTextField1 public Static using this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12347616/get-value-from-jpanel-textfield-in-another-class) but still unable to catch the values

[image]

I am using this code to fetch the values from JPanel in JPanel1. What I am doing is creating a object of JPanel in JPanel1 and then try to fetch the value.

```
LoginPanel s = new LoginPanel();
String sc=s.jTextField1.getText();
this.jLabel3.setText(sc);
```

Comment: Could you please show me the complete code so that I can help you out of it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't make a variable static for this purpose as you're breaking OOPs rules for no good reason.
2. Don't create a completely new object if you want to get the state of another object of the same type, since the two objects will be completely different instances.
3. If you need to have one object query the state of another (here the state being the text held within the JTextField), then give the the object with the JTextField a public getter field that will return the text in its JTextField and have the first object call this method when needed.
4. The first object will of course need a valid reference to the *displayed* object with the text field. How this is done will depend on the structure of your program, something we have no idea of at the moment.
5. Often the problem is **when** to obtain the text, since if you try to obtain the text **before** the user has had a chance to enter anything, then your code won't work. To avoid this, this is usually done in an event listener, and again the details will depend on the structure of your program and on code not shown.
6. Sometimes the timing is achieved by displaying the 2nd JPanel within a ***modal*** dialog window such as a JDialog or JOptionPane. This method is used most often when trying to get log on information from a user.

For better and more specific help, please make your question more informative. Show actual code, not an image of code. How much code? best would be if you could create and show us a [minimal code example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

For example, using a JOptionPane to display one JPanel and obtain text in a modal fashion:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TwoPanels extends JPanel {
    private MyPanel1 panel1 = new MyPanel1();
    private MyPanel2 panel2 = new MyPanel2();

    public TwoPanels() {
        add(panel2);
        add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Get Name") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Component parent = TwoPanels.this;
                String title = "Enter Name";
                int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
                int optionType = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent, panel1, title, optionType, messageType); 
                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    String name = panel1.getNameText();
                    panel2.setNameText(name);
                }

            }
        }));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TwoPanels mainPanel = new TwoPanels();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TwoPanels");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanel1 extends JPanel {
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);

    public MyPanel1() {
        add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        add(nameField);
    }

    public String getNameText() {
        return nameField.getText();
    }
}

class MyPanel2 extends JPanel {
    private JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);

    public MyPanel2() {
        nameField.setFocusable(false);
        nameField.setEditable(false);
        add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        add(nameField);
    }

    public void setNameText(String text) {
        nameField.setText(text);
    }

}
```